# IPv4 header included checksum but not in IPv6, why?

Tags: security, networking, ipv6, checksum

I have explored more to find why checksum is removed from ipv6 but I couldn't get exact answer, How the mutable fields in IPv6 protected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Higher layer (>=4) protocols like TCP and UDP still have their own checksums. So many lower layer protocols (<=2) already have their own checksums that having another checksum in IP (layer 3) was seen as unnecessary overhead.

It was an engineering decision.

Comment: yes, IPv4 provides checksum for header, But higher layer protocol provides checksum for payload. In IPv6 case we have checksum for payload alone through higher layer protocol, even IPv6 is mandatory to have IPsec, AH cannot provide authentication to mutable fields like source address, destination address, Hoplimit. how these mutable field protected in IPv6?

Comment: You misunderstand IPv6 and the purpose of a checksum. IPsec is not mandatory. And a checksum has nothing to do with authentication. Its only purpose is to detect transmission errors. Ethernet for example already provides that for the entire frame.

Comment: yeah.. I got your point even if IP header corrupt (for example destination address changed) in transmission, from Ethernet frame we can able to detect this transmission error using MAC address of the destination. Am I right?

Comment: The MAC address has nothing to do with it. Ethernet uses a checksum over the whole frame, and when the receiver sees that the checksum doesn't match the content the frame is discarded.